# Is the way to connect JS in embedded browser with native code?

Tags: javascript, qt, webkit, rhino

Assume, that I use WebKit inside my Qt application. Can I get access to the JS context? For example, it can be used to provide some specific APIs for user JS or to provide custom constraints over JS code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly yes, with the [addToJavaScriptWindowObject](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject)() method. Read the documentation about the [QtWebKit Bridge](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This definitely will help me with qt and webkit